# magento - price is different for cart and catalog

Tags: magento, frontend, shopping-cart, price

### Problem:

Some shown price in the catalog(right one) is different from the shown price in the cart(wrong, old price).

### Other information:

1. I compared some - working and not - Products and I found no
   difference (Dashboard and CSV.table).
2. The Data Base contains about 300.000 Products
3. I'm using Magento 1.8

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your setup, configuration, etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common reason for price difference may be outdated product flat and/or price index. Can also be misconfiguration of FPC/Varnish if present

Comment: I had the same supposition about the Index. Does anybody have some problems with the Index coused of the nr, of products? My index takes about 7 days to finish. Than it seems ok(everything green on dashboard) but I don't trust that it is true, becouse the URL-Rewrites -Rules aren't applied to all products (error in the sitemap - product Url: .../catalog/product/view/id/848437).

Comment: everyone potentially has a problem with flat index after >100k entries or with growing count of attributes. Your specific problem requires database investigation